# Access report, populate label with results of query

Tags: ms-access, report, vba

I have, what I think, is a pretty basic Access file, with a report.  The report is based off a query.  The query is:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo_NewPatient WHERE id=[Patient to view];
```

This works good, and prompts me for an id, I enter Id, and the results are the patient I want to see.  Now I want to build a report that is based on this query, but I want to create a label on the report, that populates data from the results, so I've got this code:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Label2.Caption = "Patient Name is " & PatientName & " his time in hospital is ... "
End Sub
```

I want that "PatientName" variable to be the data returned from the query.  I've tried PatientName.Value, and PatientName.Text, but each time, i get an error message:

```
 'The expression you entered has a field, control, or property name that Microsoft Office Access can't find'.
```

I'm assuming it doesn't know what "PatientName" is, perhaps because when I double click to open the report, I'm not yet prompted for the [Patient to view] variable, so the code doesn't yet know what PatientName is.  How can I correct this, or is there a better way to go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 answers.

First, in your code:

```
Label2.Caption = "Patient Name is " & PatientName & " his time in hospital is ... "
```

Move it to the `Private Sub Report_Load()` procedure. Access will then know the value of PatientName.

Or, you can assign it in the report designer. However, you can't do this with labels, but you can with textboxes. Just lock the textbox control and it act just like a label. Put it in the Control Source property, preface it with an =, and put brackets around the fieldname. So...

```
="Patient Name is " & [PatientName] & " his time in hospital is ... "
```

Comment: +1 I prefer the textbox method, no need for any routines then : )

Comment: This is perfect, thanks!  I'm going with the Report_Load() procedure, as I'll be doing some condition checking to know what to put in there.  This is great.

Comment: Oops, I spoke to soon.  This kind of works.  It appears I need to have a label on the report design with matching "PatientName" field added in order for this to work, other wise I get an error message: "Microsoft Office Access can't find the field 'PatientName' referred to in your expression".  Is there a way around this?  I don't want to have to fill my report with unnecessary labels.  Really just need one label that I will manipulate with the vb code.

Comment: If PatientName is the name of a field within the recordset the form is using, then it should work. Don't use me.PatientName. Just use [PatientName].

Comment: Hmm, maybe i'm doing something wrong, when I enter [PatientName] (no Me, tried with and without brackets) and the field is not already used as a label on the design of the report i get error: "Microsoft Office Access can't find the field 'PatientName' referred to in your expression."  If I add the field as a label on the design, then it works no error.  Are you sure this will work? Maybe i'm doing something else wrong. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like rather than doing this in VBA code, you just want to bind a column from your query (PatientName) to a label in your report. Don't do that in VBA code, do that in the report designer.

Comment: Ugh, that's right. It's a label. Hmmm, maybe turn it into a field and fool with its appearance so it looks like a lable?

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be tweaked to use Me to access the patient name field

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Label2.Caption = "Patient Name is " & Me!PatientName & " his time in hospital is ... "
End Sub
```

Edit:
It was pointed out that you can't do this on the open event.  There is another event that you can hit that will work if you have more than one record to work with.  You can use that group header paint event like this.  (I even tested it...)

```
Private Sub GroupHeader0_Paint()
    Label2.Caption = "Patient Name is " & Me!PatientName & " his time in hospital is ... "
End Sub
```